# Can a sleeve bearing adapter be used with a plain bronze bearing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bearings

I am looking for a replacement bearing for an old lathe.  The lathe spindle assemble features a collet-like bronze bearing with a nut for tightening the inner diameter.

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot find this style bearing at the required size.  Is it possible to use a bearing adapter sleeve inside a plain bronze bearing?

[image]

If not, are there any suitable alternatives that would allow me to reduce shaft runout?

Comment: Any decent machine shop should be able to manufacture that collet and threaded collar assembly...

Comment: I can too, if I only had a lathe.  The problem is that machine shops want a fortune.

Comment: Do it cheap or do it right - your choice - you have to pay for skill... Me - I would get one of my sons to make it as part of their apprenticeship - toolmakers well polymechanicien...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check McMaster and Misumi to see if a a stock bearing or flange bearing would fit. If not get one sizer smaller and (hand) ream to inside diameter needed.

https://www.mcmaster.com/#bronze-bearings/=1c3onde
https://us.misumi-ec.com/vona2/mech/M0100000000/M0107000000/